# C# college project enumeration

Tags: c#

I am currently making a easy calculator just to refresh us starting college again. 
Every thing is working fine except I was trying to assign from the keyboard ie. press plus it adds, minus it subtracts.

But when I enter a number and press the add button it does every thing right but does not clear the text box of the plus sign. Why does it do this?

```
private void tbOne_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
        {
            total1 += double.Parse(tbOne.Text);
            tbTwo.Text = tbOne.Text + btnPlus.Text;
            tbOne.Clear();

            plusButtonC = true;
            minusButtonC = false;
            divideButton = false;
            multiplyButton = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `KeyUp` event.

Comment: Are you sure you're clearing the correct textbox?

Comment: What is 'enumertion'? Is this WPF or Winforms? Please always tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indicate to the event that you have [handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) the key press to prevent the keypress being passed to standard Windows event handler. Also [SuppressKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent the key being added to the text box. Add these lines:

```
e.Handled = true;
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

It's worth noting the setting `SuppressKeyPress` also sets `Handled`, but I like to be explicit.

As noted by @GrantWinney in the comments, if it is WPF then you only need to set `Handled`.

Comment: This works for both. If it _is_ WPF, then just use `e.Handled` and omit the `e.SuppressKeyPress`.